# how to install ubuntu on android tablet

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch, samsung

How can I install Ubuntu on Samsung tablet or any android tablet.Please answer in detail.
It would be appreciated if done by video or any easy method.

Answer (score 0):

Start with this hyperlink for tablet.
http://www.ubuntu.com/tablet